# How to get and set objects on Google Datastore through Google Cloud Endpoint API (Android)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to this stuff, so I hope my question makes sense..

Basically what I want to be able to do is GET and POST data to the Google App Engine server I am running. Then, I want to be able to retrieve that same data from other devices that are accessing the server.

So let's say a user runs my app, enters in a String: "blue", and through some API that I define in an endpoint, my app takes that String and sets a GLOBAL variable that exists on my server equal to that string. ( `String color = "blue"` )

Then, if another user opens my app, I want him/her to be able to see `color = "blue"` because it has been set by another user, and if this other user wants to change the color to `color = "pink"`, then it will change across all devices again!

So, I know how to create an API / API method, as described in the Cloud-endpoints tutorial. Example :

```
public class MyEndpoint {

@ApiMethod(name = "sayHi")
public MyBean sayHi(@Named("name") String name) {
    MyBean response = new MyBean();
    response.setData("Hi, " + name);
    return response;
}
```

}

But how would I go about achieving what I have described above?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set "global" variables on GAE as your instances are constantly being created and destroyed to manage user traffic.

You'll have to use a shared instance like [Memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/) (volatile) or [datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) (persistent) to reuse values across instances